# jQuery select classes with .not, .closest and .find together

Tags: jquery

Example:

```
<div class="main">
<div><div class="left"></div></div>
<div><div class="special"></div></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<div><div class="right or center or any"></div></div>
<div><div class="special"></div></div>
</div>
```

I want to select ALL special classes but filter out if .closest('.main').find('.left')

So, I want something like this:

```
$('.special').not('.special').closest('.main').find('.left')
```

Of course it is not correct, but I didn't find any example to use .not selector with .closest  and .find together.

Comment: Are you trying to select only the element who's parent's sibling's child has the class `right` and not `left`?

Comment: @AaronEveleth I want to exclude all elements with 'left', cause there may be not only right elements, I edit the question

Comment: Ok so you want to "exclude all elements with 'left'". Does this mean you are trying to return the elements that don't match that criteria?

Comment: Also, not sure if you know this, But when you add spaces in the class attribute of an element, it treats each of those as separate classes. I understand this is irrelevant, but I want to make sure you don't actually use that practice.

Comment: @AaronEveleth I want to exclude left, yes. And I want to return all elements that matches "$('.special')" but not ('.special').closest('.main').find('.left') -> all except left :) Sorry for my english

Comment: I understand, I will work on a solution and post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
$('.special').filter(function () {
  if ($(this).closest('.main').find('.left').length > 0) {
    console.log('invalid', $(this));
  } else {
    console.log('valid', $(this));
  }
});
```

Update:

```
var list = $('.special').filter(function () {
  return ($(this).closest('.main').find('.left').length == 0);
});

console.log(list);
```

With filter you can apply your own filter and receive a list of the elements that match to it

Comment: But how can I get a list of all valid elements, should I just create a list and add all valid elements to it?

Comment: I don't have another solution in my mind so far. Would be a possibility. But why do you exactly need a list? This will already iterate through?

Comment: I have to click each of those elements every x seconds, so it's more easy to use a list, thank you, I'll try now

Comment: Yes, I just add array and push valid element to it, thank you! Just saw an update: it is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To select all elements with class `special`, but exclude with your criteria, do the following:

```
$('.special').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).closest('.main').find('.left')) {
        // logs element to console
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Another way to do this, based on your HTML, is like this:

```
$('.special').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).parent('div').siblings('div').children('.left')) {
        // logs element to console
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Also, inside the `div`'s with class `main` you seem to have an extra(unnecessary) `div` around your inner most `div`s. I suggested removing those and updating your code accordingly to keep your code clean.